# Typescript React, render element conditionally

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm making a `Button` component that can behave as an `anchor` element when passed a certain condition, the condition is an `as` prop `'button' | 'a'`

Button.types.ts

```
interface RootProps {
  size?: "small" | "medium" | "large";
  // ....
}

type RootButtonProps = RootProps & ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & { as?: "button" }; // "button" is the default value

type RootAnchorProps = RootProps & AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> & { as: "a" };

export type ButtonProps = RootButtonProps | RootAnchorProps;
```

Button.tsx

```
const Button = forwardRef<unknown, ButtonProps>(({ children, size, ...props }, ref) => {
  // ...

  const element = useMemo(() => {
    switch(props.as) {
      case "a": return <a { ...props }>{children}</a> // props inferred correctly
      case "button": return <button { ...props }>{children}</button> // props inferred correctly
    }
  });

  return element;
})
```

usage

```
<Button as="button" href="./">CLICK</Button> // compiler error (which is the correct behavior)

<Button as="a" href="./">CLICK</Button> // no compiler error (which is the correct behavior)

<Button href="./">CLICK</Button> // no compiler error (which is not the correct behavior since the default value of `as` is `button`)
```

When declaring the `as` prop as mandatory and passing `as="button"` explicitly the error goes way, is there a correct way to have the default value of the `as` prop = `button` without having to declare it all the time and have the correct attributes inferred?

Here is a more detailed reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-https-gys30?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue, with the last example I do get a compiler error. However these should probably be two separate components anyway rather than one that's called `Button` but can be a link.

Comment: My answer was not sufficient @Sam, hence i removed it. You should add the sandbox link here

Comment: @HenryWoody strange, what is the error? because in the sandbox I don't see an error in the last example `<Button href="./">CLICK</Button>` which should give an error.

Comment: @Sam oh sorry that was a typo, mean't "don't get a compiler error".